# How to get only NEW text from TextBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, textbox

```
private void tbLog_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Get only NEW text added to Log
}

/*
    LOG
    old message...
    old message...
    old message...
    old message...
    NEW message...
    NEW message...
    NEW message...
    NEW message...
    NEW message...
*/
```

How to I get only NEW text from the TextBox?

Comment: Perhaps you might like to clarify what you mean by "new". Do you mean any new text added to the end since the last TextChanged event was fired? PS. Maybe look at the TextChangedEventArgs.Changes property.

Comment: I was looking into that, but I can't get the debugger to break so I can see what's in e.Changes. I just want the new text that triggered the TextChanged event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
private string old_text = "";

private void tbLog_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if(old_text != tbLog.Text)
    {
        writeLog(tbLog.Text);
        old_text = tbLog.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid that much data in 1 hit. Doing it that way, I would be handling and writing the entire textbox everytime.

Comment: How much data is in your text box?

Comment: Then use the `KeyDown` event to capture key strokes and record them on your own (also saving the cursor position). Note that this might get tricky if you allow copypaste, etc. Also is your text that long?

Comment: There's no typing in my log, it's updated by other objects as tasks are run. How will that work with no keyboard input?

Comment: Ah ... then you're "screwed". You'll have to work with the full text or get your other object to send the changed parts only.

Comment: I'm not sure how to quantify my textbox data, but the suggested method creates other issues down the road. I can't rewrite my entire log everytime the text changes. I would like to just append the new text to the log. I don't want to compare my old log to the new one and somehow add only the new data either (that could lead to errors).

Comment: How about using a `ListBox` for logging instead? You'd be able to access each entry separately, the user would be able to scroll, etc.?

Comment: Yea, I think I'm gonna have to do that or run a tread in the background worker on a timer that checks, updates and clears the textbox. Also have a manual force save button. I was hoping I could just have a nice little line of code in the text changed function. Oh well. Thanks for the help!

Comment: what "header" do I have to include to get TextChangedEventArgs ?

Comment: Hm? This should be available by default, once you add `System.Windows.Forms`.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you should be using the [`TextChangedEventArgs.Changes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textchangedeventargs.changes.aspx) property:

```
var fullText = tbLog.Text;
if (e.Changes.Any())
{
    var additions = e.Changes.Where(tc => tc.AddedLength > 0);
    var newTexts = additions.Select(tc => fullText.Substring(tc.Offset, tc.AddedLength));

    // TODO: Do stuff with the new pieces of text
}
```

Comment: This is very odd. I tried this solution, but like everything else I tried, nothing is working when the event is firing. It won't even honor the breakpoint when the event is fired. I added this and a general exception around the entire thing, so no errors are being thrown `foreach (var txt in newTexts)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(txt);
                    }`. The log is updating.. and when I remove all the code and leave the auto scrolling code, that works, but nothing else will. Even if I just put `MessageBox.Show("I WORKED");`, nothing, no MB...

Comment: I have to apologize. I don't know how it happened or what.. but VS must've been glitching or something. The auto scroll to end code started only working about 50% of my debugs, then it stopped. I went and found that somehow the event was removed from the XAML code.. Your code above works flawlessly!! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3):

For desktop WPF text boxes, you should be able to use [TextChangedEventArgs.Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textchangedeventargs.changes.aspx) to enumerate the changes. Note a single event may contain several changes.

The [TextChange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.textchange.aspx) class has Offset, AddedLength, and RemovedLength properties that give you the exact range of characters that were changed.

Answer (score 0):

```
private void textTx1Asc_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{                          
    string s;

    //get only the new chars
    s = textTx1Asc.Text;
    s = s.Remove(0, prev_len);          

    //update prev_len for next time
    prev_len = textTx1Asc.TextLength;

    //s contains only the new characters, process here                
}
```